# When is a theme `isEditable` or `isDeletable` in the admin?

Tags: magento2, theme, magento-2.1.2

I *think* I remember seeing a delete button at some point recently on CE 2.1.2 when I go to Content > Designs > Themes > select a theme. Now, I don't for any themes I have (default ones and a custom one). Upon looking at the code, a theme can be deleted if the below condition is satisfied.

```
/**
 * Check if theme is deletable
 *
 * @return bool
 */
public function isDeletable()
{
    return $this->isEditable();
}

/**
 * Check if theme is editable
 *
 * @return bool
 */
public function isEditable()
{
    return self::TYPE_PHYSICAL != $this->getType();
}
```

I can't make sense of this because a theme is typically saved as `TYPE_PHYSICAL`, and I don't see how it's ever changed. Therefore, `isEditable()` doesn't seem like it would ever return true because it's evaluating `0 != 0`.

It appears themes were designed to be added in CLI and perhaps managed entirely via CLI? I have a custom theme record in the `theme` table, but the theme files are actually not there. I'm trying to clean up the database of this remnant data and re-install a new theme.  Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

Found the answer. See `Magento\Theme\Controller\Adminhtml\System\Design\Theme\Delete:execute`. It says ...

> Only virtual theme is possible to delete